# CodeIgniter unable to show data from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm unable to view data from my database using these codes. Just echoing **NO Records Returned**

*controller :*

```
 public function get_task()
    {
        $data = array();

        if( $query = $this->model_users->getTask()){
            $data ['records'] = $query ;
        }

        $this->load->view('Reg_Login/members', $data);
    }
```

*members.php :*

```
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records  as $row): ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->tname ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->time; ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h2>No Records Returned</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*model_users* :

```
public function getTask()
      {
         $query = $this->db->get('tasks');
         return $query->result();
       }
```

Comment: whats in your log? are there are erros? any apache logs? also try looking into mysql query log to see if any query is being executed.

Comment: @unixmiah There are no errors. The query inside `<?php else :?>` were executed which is No Records Returned. Check my view file's last para.

Comment: why are you using `:` with else statement. use `{` for your `if` `else` block. and add  `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` on top of your method and check what query is being executed.

Comment: The {} aren't necessary. <?php if(condition): ?> <HTML CODE> <?php else: ?> <DIFFERENT HTML CODE> <?php endif; ?> Works perfectly fine. It looks cleaner too.

Comment: @KamranAdil Yap @Cro is right but thanks to your idea of adding `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` 

It helped me out to find what query was executing and I found that I didn't invoke the method properly. 

Now my problem is solved. Thank you guys for your efforts ! :)

Comment: @Vickel I already mentioned that in my above comment. No error with the code, with `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` I found that I just didn't invoke my method properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no error in the code.

By using `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in my `controller` I found that, I just didn't invoke my `method` properly.

That's all, you can use these codes to `fetch data from DB` and show in your `view file`.